# How do you replace a DOM element with a ul list made from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replace an image in my HTML with a list whose items are elements of an array I've looped through.

I've been able to locate some separate info online of how to createElement and how to replaceElement, but I'm having trouble combining these concepts. Especially since I have my program formatted to where two IIFE's are talking to each other. So far, the only output I've gotten with the code I have below is only a listing of the first item in my array. No other list items show after that first one.

```js
// Separate IIFE
const calcController = (function() {

  const Order = function(item, pr) {
    this.item = item;
    this.pr = pr;
  };

  Order.prototype.displayOrder = function() {
    return `${this.item}: $${this.pr}`;
  };

  let orders = [];

  return {
    getOrders: function() {

      for (let x = 0; x < orders.length; x++) {
        return orders[x].displayOrder();
      }
    }
  };
})();

// Separate IIFE
const mainController = (function(calcCtrl) {


  let updateDOM = function() {
    let el = document.querySelector('img');
    let newEl = document.createElement('ul');
    newEl.innerHTML = calcCtrl.getOrders();

    newEl.setAttribute('class', 'receipt');
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);

  };

})(calcController);
```

```html
<div id='imageContainer'>
  <img id='order' height='350px'>
</div>
```

I'm hoping for an unorganized list of the orders array elements. Such as...
    -Hamburger: $3.99
    -Fries: $1.99
    -Soda: $1.99
    etc...

Answer (score 0):

Two problems at the moment.

1. There is no call to `updateDOM` function. You just need to call it once.
2. There are no items in the `orders` array.

```js
// Separate IIFE
const calcController = (function() {

  const Order = function(item, pr) {
    this.item = item;
    this.pr = pr;
  };

  Order.prototype.displayOrder = function() {
    return `${this.item}: $${this.pr}`;
  };

  // Define some orders
  let orders = [new Order("a", 1)];

  return {
    getOrders: function() {
      for (let x = 0; x < orders.length; x++) {
        return orders[x].displayOrder();
      }
    }
  };
})();

// Separate IIFE
const mainController = (function(calcCtrl) {


  let updateDOM = function() {
    let el = document.querySelector('img');
    let newEl = document.createElement('ul');
    newEl.innerHTML = calcCtrl.getOrders();

    newEl.setAttribute('class', 'receipt');
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);

  };

  // Call the function
  updateDOM()

})(calcController);
```

```html
<div id='imageContainer'>
  <img id='order' height='350px'>
</div>
```